# How I can use Polymorphism to return multiple results and use multi behaviours in the same time

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 9 and I have a request can contains :

- Parameter called SEASON the value can be an `array` or null
  so `SEASON` parameter can be an `array` and can be also `null`
- Parameter called EXPIRY can be an `array` and can be also `null`

I have two classes one for the `SEASON` feature and the other class for `EXPIRY` both they extends from `Repository`. and both have a method called `execute` that return an array

```
abstract class Repository 
{
     abstract public function execute(): array;
}


class Expiry extends Repository
{
   public function execute()
   {
       return ['The Request contain Expiry Parameter, and seasonal behaviours is done'];
   }
}


class Season extends Repository
{
   public function execute()
   {
       return ['The Request contain Season Parameter, and expiry behaviours is done'];
   }
}
```

I would like to call execute method of Season class if my request contains SEASON, or call the execute method of expiry if my request contains Expiry. OR Call both of them and merge the execute return of execute in one array so I can have as result.

```
['The Request contain Expiry Parameter, and seasonal behaviours is done', 'The Request contain Expiry Parameter, and expiry behaviours is done']
```

That's what I tried inside my controller :

```
public function bootstrap($data)
{
    $parseTopics = Helper::parseTopicsRequest();

    $basicProgram = new BasicProgramRepository();
    $seasonalProgram = new SeasonalProgramRepository($parseTopics['SEASONAL']);


    $object = count($parseTopics['SEASONAL']) ? $seasonalProgram : $basicProgram;
    // Polymorphism
    return $object->execute();
}
```

Question 1 :
I'm not sure if I should use this way or something like to fix my need:

```
$employe = new Program(new BasicProgramRepository());
```

Expected Result :
The expected result depends on if I have season parameter and expiry. What I want to achieve is to use different behaviours ( execute method )

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. The way you're initialising is ok, but one improvement you can make is using an `if/else` instead of instantiating both classes and only creating the one you need before storing it directly into `$object`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to achieve Polymorphism method, it will be better creating repository or something only for managing that logic.

here is sample.

```
class SampleRepository
{
    /**
     * repository instance value
     *
     * @var string[] | null
     */
    private $sampleArray; // maybe here is SEASON or EXPIRY or null

    /**
     * constructor
     *
     * @param string[] | null $sampleArray
     */
    public function __construct($sampleArray)
    {
        $this->sampleArray = $sampleArray;
    }

    /**
     * execute like class interface role
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        return (!$this->sampleArray) ? [] : $this->getResult();
    }

    /**
     * get result
     *
     * @return array
     */
    private function getResult()
    {
        // maybe pattern will be better to manage another class or trait.
        $pattern = [
            "SEASON" => new Season(),
            "EXPIRY" => new Expiry()
        ];
        return collect($this->sampleArray)->map(function($itemKey){
            $requestClass = data_get($pattern,$itemKey);
            if (!$requestClass){ // here is space you don't expect class or canIt find correct class
                return ["something wrong"];
            }
            return $requestClass->execute();
        })->flatten();
    }
}
```

and you can call like this.

```
$sampleRepository  = new SampleRepository($sampleValue); // expect string[] or null like ["SEASON"],["SEASON","EXPIRY"],null
    $result = $sampleRepository->execute(); // [string] or [string,string] or []
```

this approach is only what your parameter is secified value.
if your return result is almost same both of Season class and Expiry class, it will be better to manage on trait. (that is $pattern on sample code)

try some.

I read comments,so following..

For example, it prefers to be only getting result of getResult().
so, some pattern and so many logics shouldn't be written on getResult();

If you use trait, this is sample.
first, you need to create managing behaviors class.

Behavior.php

```
<?php 
namespace App\Repositories;

class Behavior
{
    use Behavior\BehaviorTrait;
    // if you need to add another pattern, you can add trait here.
}
```

and then, you need to create Behavior directory at same level place.
you move that directory, you create trait file like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories\Behavior;

trait BehaviorTrait
{
    public static function findAccessibleClass(string $itemKey)
    {
      return data_get([
        "SEASON" => new Season(),
        "EXPIRY" => new Expiry()
      ],$itemKey);
    }
}
```

findAccessibleClass() method has responsible of finding correct class.

then, you call this method like this.

```
private function getResult()
    {
        return collect($this->sampleArray)->map(function($itemKey){
            $requestClass = Behavior::findAccessibleClass($itemKey); // fix here.
            if (!$requestClass){ // here is space you don't expect class or canIt find correct class
                return ["something wrong"];
            }
            return $requestClass->execute();
        })->flatten();
    }
```

if your code is so much in getResult(), you will be better to separate code for responsible.

To create Behavior trait, getResult don't need to have responsible of behavior logic. it will be easy testing or fixable in short.

hope well.

Comment: what do you mean by  // maybe pattern will be better to manage another class or trait. in your comment

Comment: Laravel is a fully managed application.
So,it's important to design and what responsibility each function or service should have.
Of course, writing code everything in one class also works in laravel.

Comment: However, to keep creating app and functionality is extended, the code becomes disorganized and prone to chaos.
Traits can be used for recalled default values, or for a little bit function.
Please check the Laravel official documentation for how to use traits.

Comment: In this case, when the value to call a specific class is the parameter value, it would be more extensible to create a trait that manages the parameter value and class. If managed by traits, the responsibility of managing parameter values ​​and classes is completed only by the logic combined with traits.

Comment: can you please give me an example using trait please

Comment: I fixed answer. please refer it. :)